# Failing to add xml element in a xml formatted structure

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

For some reason when I append element to xml file, it's written in one line, i.e. not formatted

Original xml:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>test1</name>
</property>
</configuration>

my $parser =XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    =$parser->parse_file($file) or die $!;
my $root   =$doc->getDocumentElement;
my $searchPath="/configuration";
my ($val)=$root->findnodes($searchPath);
my $propTag=$doc->createElement("property");
$val->appendChild($propTag);
my $nameTag=$doc->createElement("name");
$nameTag->appendTextNode($name);
$propTag->appendChild($nameTag);
$doc->setDocumentElement($root);
$doc->toFile($file,1);
```

Which resulted with:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>test1</name>
 </property>
  <property><name>test2</name></property></configuration>
```

Instead of:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>test1</name>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>test2</name>
  </property>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Whitespace can be significant in XML. XML::LibXML doesn't add whitespace you don't tell it to add.

Comment: I tried changing the `format` parameter in `toFile` from 1 to 2, but that gave a very 'spaced out' file. Don't know how to fix this one

Comment: Yes, I tried it too. It's very strange because adding a new element should a basic action when working with XML

Comment: Adding a new element works. You want to add an element and some text nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `xmllint --format` on the output of your Perl script.